# extend an existing permission with a new time slot using tapkey API

Tags: tapkey

the integration of the tapkey service into our app is almost complete.

- we are able to connect tapkey user account with the sharepar accounts
- we are able to connect the locks with sharepar objects
- we are able to set up grands for the locks during the booking time

The problem we are facing is how to set up more than one timeslot per grant, as it is possible with tapkey app and portal. Is there any way to do this through the API?

Answer (score 0):

To define multiple time slots use the `timeRestrictionIcal` property of the Grant which allows you to specify the permission in an Ical format:
https://developers.tapkey.io/openapi/tapkey_access_management_web_api_v1/#/Grants/Grants_Put

This allows to specify multiple events or also recurrent events.